# What causes a library (.so) to be copied to devel/lib

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I've got a project comprising approximately 30 packages. Some of these packages define libraries in the CMakeLists, using the add_library and target_link_libraries functions.
I am wondering why only some of these packages create shared objects in devel/lib while others aren't.

Example:
I've got a package (for simplicity say package "a") which defines a library. This package is referenced as <runtime_dep> by another package (b). Sadly, when running catkin build, no shared object is copied to devel/lib, resulting in runtime failure in node b.

EDIT:
Thank you for your answers, but that doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.

I am using catkin_tools to build my project. I configure my build with catkin config --no-install, hence no install targets are executed.

Still, catkin puts some libraries in devel/lib. If I look at the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH after the build, I can see that the devel/lib directory is included there. My problem is that I don't know which statement causes a defined library to be copied there at build time.

All packages define the libraries using add_library, target_link_libraries and catkin_package(... LIBRARIES ), still some of them are not copied to devel/lib

Package definition of a package which doesn't create a shared object in devel/lib:

```
... 
add_library(m_controllers    
     src/general.cpp    
     src/passthrough.cpp )

add_dependencies(m_controllers ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}) 
target_link_libraries(m_controllers ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

catkin_package(    
CATKIN_DEPENDS
....    
INCLUDE_DIRS include    
LIBRARIES m_controllers 
) 
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224698/what-causes-a-library-(.so)-to-be-copied-to-devel/lib/) by [martin1412](https://answers.ros.org/users/25296/martin1412/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-21**:
To add to @Akif's answer: note that for things to work in a *devel workspace*, you don't actually need to have any `install(..)` rules, just properly setup `catkin_package(.. LIBRARIES ..)` statements.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-21**:
Seeing your [other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/223477/pythonpath-is-not-set-correctly-by-source-develsetupbash/), can you describe how you setup your workspace(s), and how you interact with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to @F.Brosseau's answer, you can check [this page](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html) for a general how-to on **Building and installing C++ libraries and headers**.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try to add the following at the end of your CMakeLists.txt file :

```
install(TARGETS
   a
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   )
```

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Order matters in catkin-ised `CMakeLists.txt`, please re-order the statements to follow the order given in [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt - Overall Structure and Ordering](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Overall_Structure_and_Ordering).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martin1412](https://answers.ros.org/users/25296/martin1412/) on 2016-01-21**:
The problem seems to be related to the order of commands in my CMakeLists.txt Thank you gvdhoorn!

After moving the add_library, add_dependencies and target_link_libraries statements below catkin_package, the .so file was created in devel/lib